# How to update centos6.2 kernel, yum install success but failed to change /etc/grub.conf?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum

I want to update kernel from 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 to 2.6.32-754.23.1.el6 with yum install.

install success but failed to change /etc/grub.conf
[image]

try "yum reinstall kernel" but failed again.
[image]

I've tried to change /etc/grub.conf manually but is told 
[image]

I can not even remove the swap file /boot/grub/grub_con.swp with root(even chmod 744 is success)

[image]

system: CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
kernel:2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64

Edit with nano failed
[image]
the swap file for ../boot/grub/grub.conf is also /boot/grub/grub_con.swp
[image]

I can add file to /boot/grub/ but can not remove.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the file using `nano /etc/grub.conf`?

Comment: @Ned64 failed, both failed with /etc/grub.conf  and  “../boot/grub/grub.conf”,  I've append that in my question description.   But how can I have a " ../boot/grub/grub.conf"？ Is that because I am in a Virtual Linux Environment?

Comment: Can you write to the disk at all?  Please test by issuing `touch /boot/grub/test`. Also, I am assuming all commands are entered as root (test by `id`), right?

Comment: I can add file to /boot/grub/ but can not remove.  I'veappend detail in question description.

Comment: @Ned64 always with root, add "id" test.

Comment: Please boot a rescue system (or any graphical system from live/installation DVD/ISO) and check the filesystem of all system partitions (normal `/` and `/boot` if they are two separate partitions) using `fsck -f /dev/sdXn`, setting X and n as appropriate (see `lsblk` when rescue system is booted).

Comment: @Ned64 after some other trial, I found it's another security software interrupt this operation. I just uninstall the software “echo y|/usr/local/yunsuo_agent/uninstall" and "yum reinstall kernel" and reboot system, it works.      Thank you all the same.